# Error when adding a CASE statement combined with the IN operator "Operand Type Clash: DATE is incompatible with INT"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL query which attempts to create groupings with regard to Time such as FISCAL Quarters and Fiscal Periods etc.

When I execute the query, an error is returned with the following message

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

I tried to rewrite the query in different ways many times, but unfortunately as I do not have enough knowledge on the topic I can't seem to figure out why. However, I do think the error occurs due to the CASE statement written combined with IN.

My code's given below.

```
SELECT d1.*,
       case when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (1,2,3,4,5,6) then 'H1'
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (7,8,9,10,11,12) then 'H2'
            else NULL
       end  AS FISCAL_HALF_YEAR_TXT,
       case when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (1,2,3,4,5,6) then 1
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (7,8,9,10,11,12) then 2
            else NULL
       end  AS FISCAL_HALF_YEAR,
       rep_acc_period as FISCAL_PERIOD,
       cast (rep_acc_period as nvarchar) as FISCAL_PERIOD_TXT,
       case when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (1,2,3) then 'Q1'
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (4,5,6) then 'Q2'
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (7,8,9) then 'Q3'
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (10,11,12) then 'Q4'
            else NULL
       end  AS FISCAL_QUARTER_TXT,
       case when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (1,2,3) then 1
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (4,5,6) then 2
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (7,8,9) then 3
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (10,11,12) then 4
            else NULL
       end  AS FISCAL_QUARTER,
       case when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (1,2,3,4) then 1
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (5,6,7,8) then 2
            when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (9,10,11,12) then 3
            else NULL
       end  AS FISCAL_TERTIAL,
       rep_acc_year as FISCAL_YEAR,
       rep_acc_year * 100 + rep_acc_period as FISCAL_YEAR_PERIOD,
       id as IS_ID   
   FROM TIME_TAB d1
```

The data types of the selected columns are given below.

- rep_acc_period - bigint
- FISCAL_HALF_YEAR_TXT - varchar(2)
- rep_acc_period/FISCAL_PERIOD - bigint
- FISCAL_PERIOD_TXT - nvarchar
- FISCAL_QUARTER_TXT - varchar(2)
- FISCAL_QUARTER - int
- FISCAL_TERTIAL - int
- rep_acc_year/FISCAL_YEAR - bigint
- FISCAL_YEAR_PERIOD - bigint

Any help on this?

Comment: What datatype is "d1.rep_acc_period"? An INT or DATETIME? If the later, that's why. SQL cannot compare INTs with DATETIME.

Comment: In SQL Server its a `CASE` expression *not* statement.

Comment: We need to know the datatypes of all the columns you are selecting if you want us to help. However you can work out the offending column by commenting out all but one case expression and working through them one at a time to identify the column causing the issue.

Comment: @DaleK . . . In ALL databases, it is a `case` expression.  Some database scripting languages do support `case` statements, but the use in a `select` query is always as an expression.

Comment: @Fandango68 the data type of d1.rep_acc_period is a bigint.

Comment: @DaleK yes, it's an expression and the data types of the columns are now given above.

Comment: And which part of the query gave an error when you working through them one at a time?

Comment: The first line itself actually. "case when isnull(d1.rep_acc_period,0) in (1,2,3,4,5,6) then 'H1'"

Comment: Something is missing in your question then, because all those datatypes have nothing related to DATETIME, which the error is implying. Are you not telling us everything?